# AngularJS ng-show with Bootstrap visible-phone

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<div ng-show="loggedIn()" class="visible-phone">Show only on phone and if logged in.</div>
```

And in JS:

```
$rootScope.loggedIn = function () {
    return window.usr ? true : false;
};
```

But the element is always shown regardless of `loggedIn()` value. Any solution for this? (or at least workaround)

Comment: Can you recreate the issue with a fiddle and pass it along? It would be much easier to see what you are facing!

Comment: Guessing here... If you are changing window.usr outside of AngularJS, then you'll have to notify AngularJS about the change.  See $scope.$apply, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Adding to what @mark-rajcok is recommending, for testability you should also look to be using $window instead of directly using window.

Answer (score 0):

If window.usr was set to 'true' prior to your $rootScope.loggedIn function was called then this would work. I suspect this will not be the case.  I would recommend rethinking your direct use of window object. If you were to encapsulate your authentication logic in an angular service, you would be much better served.

I would highly recommend you look at [Witold Szczerba's http auth implementation](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth)